# Why does this appear different in anything else than blender?

Tags: export, error

I have this model:
[image]

But when I export it, it looks like this in the windows 3d viewer and anywhere else than blender:
[image]

No matter if I export as [.obj](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PcPR6dT_4SvqCN6b1DcOAbEWJimpz-Z6/view?usp=sharing) or [.fbx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ITihRAcFY4Zv9swacOxRDu3wGUQquldh/view?usp=sharing).

Here is it in [.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cOE7s7lHeVLap25vttKvuYB3OSXj1WHK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

I've scaled down your object in order to see the problem: 1 is your building, 2 is the landscape you show, which is far away and much bigger:

[image]

What you can do is switch to *Edit* mode and *X-Ray* mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), select the building with the lasso or the box selection tool, inverse the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and remove the vertices with <kbd>X</kbd>, or simply separate the building with <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate) > Selection*.

Comment: thank you so much